# How to find multple results in Arrays with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, find

How i make this?

```
const arrays = [
    { servername: "MyServer", owner: "Evelyn" },
    { servername: "Minecraft Server", owner: "Maria" },
    { servername: "You really are reading this? xd", owner: "RaymondG" }
];

const Data = arrays.find(data => data.servername.includes("a"));
// Result: { servername: "Minecraft Server", owner: "Maria" }

// I want get this: [{ servername: "Minecraft Server", owner: "Maria" }, { servername: "You really are reading this? xd", owner: "RaymondG" }];
```

In summary, I would like to know how to obtain the data of an Array that contains certain requirements, I have tried with for-of, but the problem with this is that with large data, it usually takes a long time...

Comment: use filter instead

Answer (score 2):

use Array.filter instead of Array.find:

```
const Data = arrays.filter(data => data.servername.includes("a"));
// [{ servername: "Minecraft Server", owner: "Maria" }, { servername: "You really are reading this? xd", owner: "RaymondG" }];
```

Comment: Hahaha, don't stain, I don't know what's wrong with me, I've forgotten that function, thank you very much mate